# Lemma 11.42 Rotman's algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> This is lemma 11.42, pg 355, of Rotman's Algebraic Topology. 
>   The context is we are trying to determine an explicit map for "connecting homomorphism".

[image]

> where $i:A \rightarrow X$ is inclusion. This is Rotman's proof.

[image]

> Then there is calculations here giving explicit map $\theta:[S^n, Mi] \rightarrow \pi_{n+1}(X,A)$

[image]

[image]

> The last statement is unclear to me. He claims we have all the maps in the original diagram.
>
> **But between $\pi_{n+1}(X)$ and $[S^n,\Omega X]$ we have the series of isomoprhisms**
>   $$\pi_{n+1}(X)=[S^{n+1},X] \cong [\Sigma S^n, X ] \cong [S^n, \Omega X]$$
>   where the first, albeit natural, isomorphism, has a **choice**.
>
> Hence, the question is how is the map $(\Omega^nk)_*$ actually defined pointwise? Its domain should be $[S^{n+1}, X]$ instead of $[S^n, \Omega X]$.

---

Here is our map: 
$$\Omega^nk_*:[S^{n+1}, X] \xrightarrow{\varphi_*} [ \Sigma S^n, X] \simeq [ S^n , \Omega X] \xrightarrow{k_*} [S^n, Mi]$$

The first map clearly depends on our choice $\varphi$. At which point is $\varphi_*$ cancelled again?

Comment: As you already mentioned, $\Omega k$ involves certain choice of identification $S^{n+1}\cong \Sigma S^n$ (that is, $\Omega k$ is only explicitly given as a map between $[\Sigma S^n, X]$ and $[S^n,\Omega X]$, not between $[S^{n+1},X]$ and $[S^{n},\Omega X]$. So it is nonsense to ask for a pointwise formula for $\Omega k$ without settling the choice. Here the point is that the a choice changes all the first row and vertical arrows in consistent way so that it is commutative no matter what your choice is.

Comment: @cjackal, I think my problem is I don't see how that would be consistent. Do you mind writing it out?

Comment: I don't really understand your argument too: how is the diagram being commutative enough to guarantee commutativity of original diagram? There must be some poitn wise check(?)

Comment: It is not that difficult to see. Let $\phi:S^{n+1}\to \Sigma S^n$ be your favorite identification. Then the vertical arrows are actually $(\mathrm{adjunction})\circ\phi^{-1}$, and the maps on the first row are $\phi^{-1}\circ \Omega f\circ \phi$ for appropriate map $f$. (ie, $f=k,i'$) This is in principle similar to the basis change formula in linear algebra.

Comment: Of course you do need a pointwise check at some point, but I assume you already check it for standard adjunction $[\Sigma X,Y]\cong [X,\Omega Y]$.

Comment: Edit: I am still stuck at element wise chase. @cjackal, sorry, may you please write all the maps?

Comment: @cjackal, i don't think the vertical maps are $\tau \circ \phi_*^{-1}$. where $\tau$ is adjunction. $\phi_*$ here is $$[\Sigma S^0, \Omega X ] \rightarrow [ S^n, \Omega X]$$
We are taking the induced map from isomoprhism  $\phi: \Sigma S^0 \cong S^n$.

Answer (score 1):

All right, I made a mess a bit in the comments. Let me make it clear with diagrams.

Note that by iterating as many as you want, we can just consider the adjunction $[S^{n+1},X]\to [S^n,\Omega X]$ instead of iterated adjunction as in Rotman. Actually, this does not have exactly the form of adjunction; instead it is a composition of $(\phi^{-1})_*:[S^{n+1},X]\to [\Sigma S^{n},X]$ and the usual adjunction $[\Sigma S^n,X]\to [S^n,\Omega X]$ where $\phi:S^{n+1}\to \Sigma S^n$ is your favorite identification between $S^{n+1}$ and $\Sigma S^n$. And there is no particular choices made in horizontal arrows.

But note that the two-row diagram is in fact a three-row diagram:
[image]

(I just realized that I reversed all the vertical arrows, my bad. It doesn't affect underlying math as vertical parts are isomorphisms though.)

Here the horizontal arrows are induced by continuous maps acting on the second entry of the bracket. Here the commutativity of the first square is standard. (At any rate, it is the standard adjunction.) And the commutativity of the second square is just obvious; it just says the bifunctoriality of the bracket $[-,-]$.

And of course the dependency on $\phi$ is only on the second square.